# How to check health of an Endpoint using Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, http

I am trying to create a service in Java and Spring that tests the health a variety of endpoints that do various things like delete accounts, get account data, create accounts etc. My inital approach was to perform a request and check to see if the return code is 200 using `RestTemplate`. The issue is that when testing things like delete account, i need to have a dummy account to delete, and it gets more complex with accounts that rely on one another. My question is how can I ping the health of an endpoints such as:

```
https://foobar.com/deleteBar
```

without actually performing a delete or the function of the endpoint?

Comment: You should not check individual endpoints rather check the health of the entire application. The app should provide you the healthcheck endpoint

Comment: Im working in an ecosystem where each endpoint is a separate running app

Comment: Then each app should have a health check endpoint. If they are spring boot apps, they comes with inbuilt health check endpoints  `/actuator/health`.

Answer (score 1):

*Spring Actuator* brings all the things you need - in this particular situation, a healthcheck endpoint (*/actuator/health/*). 
If application is running safely, an Http GET request on this endpoint will return JSON message containing text like `{ "status": "UP" }`. 
To add this endpoint to your application, all you have to do is add following dependency to your project (in this example, Maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I do not have control over the API, I am simply making the request

Comment: Hmm. If the API you are using has been constructed in a good manner, then it'd be a nice idea to follow HTTP return codes.  
In example, return code of 500 informs you that there is a problem with API workflow, while 2xx codes let you know, that everything is OK. Moreover, even 'bad' codes like 4xx let you know, that API is still working.

Comment: will a 500 code mean that is it up and the request caused an error? does any error code other than 404 mean that the endpoint is still alive?

Comment: 500 means *Internal Server Error*, so the possible problem is on the server's (API) side. Your request may cause it only if the server has some internal issues with processing this request (and it means that it's probably been constructed in a poor manner).  
All the non-5xx codes, like 4xx, 2xx etc mean that server is up and working well, specifically 4xx codes mean that there is some problem from your side (e.g. bad request, or you are unauthorized), but server is still perfectly healthy.
See all the Http codes: https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html